# How to query "list data" on android app startup with firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having trouble figuring out how I can query my firebase database when my android app starts. I know the relevant code must go into the onCreate method but I am unsure what code I require

Comment: The quick start on https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html says to do `Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseIO-demo.com/");  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) { System.out.println(snap.getName() + " -> " + snap.getValue()); } @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { } });` Doesn't that work for you? If so, can you share **your** code?

Comment: As Frank mentioned, there's not enough data here to go on. You can certainly query data when your app starts and there are examples and docs on Firebase explaining how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to connect to your Firebase DB `/.info/connected`. Then, you need to login `rootFirebase.auth(token, new Firebase.AuthListener...`. And once you know that you've successfully logged in, you can query your data.

I would write this part in a separate class, and invoke its functions in `onCreate`. Also, you can pass in a listener, such that once you're connected, your `Activity` gets the callback, then you can proceed.

Comment: so there is not way I can just query the database with authenticating, it is just a prototype, no authentication needed.

Comment: I think you might be able to do it (haven't tried though), but you might need to change the Security Rules (on the left side of the dashboard).